# how to grab value from v-model by array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

script.

```
data() {
    return {
        bankList: [ 'Apple','Banana'],
        bankInfo: [{
                bankOwner: '',
                bankName: [],
                bankAccount: '',
            }],
     }
```

and HTML code

```
<table class="table table-bordered" v-for="(item, index) in bankInfo">

<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control">
<option default>선택</option>
<option v-for="money in bankList" v-model="item.bankName"> {{money}} 
</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I tried to get out of the bankName value, but it showed only as array[0]

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? b/c I see many errors, the biggest being using `v-model` on `<option>`, v-model should be on the `<select>` tag

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake, after changed v-model to select tag from option. now it's work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the `v-model` on the `<select>` tag not on `<option>` tag

Bind the `value` attribute on the `<option>` tag

```
<table class="table table-bordered" v-for="(item, index) in bankInfo">

<div class="form-group">
<select v-model="item.bankName"  class="form-control">
<option default>선택</option>
<option v-for="money in bankList" :value='money' > {{money}} 
</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: after changed v-model to select tag from option. now it's work! but default value doesn't show.